# How to read SMPS files in SCIP 6.0?

Tags: scip, stochastic

I have installed the SCIP 6.0 optimization suite and am trying to read SMPS format to solve a stochastic programming instance: DCAP.cor, DCAP.tim, DCAP.sto

When I type

```
SCIP> read DCAP.cor
```

Then, it seems that SCIP reads the .cor file just as a .mps file.

So is there a way to let SCIP read three SMPS files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a file DCAP.smps which just lists the three files that define your instance, e.g.,

```
DCAP.cor
DCAP.tim
DCAP.sto
```

For an example, see the .smps files in the `check/instances/Stochastic/` directory of your SCIP installation.

The matching is not simply done by name, because you often define multiple instances based on the same core and time file and just exchange the stochastics file.